# Synchronize two CalDAV servers

Tags: ubuntu, caldav

In short, I'm looking for a solution on Ubuntu/Linux that will allow me to keep two calendars, each managed by a remote CalDAV server with a web interface, in sync, in the sense that any change I make on one of calendars through its web interface would be propagated, with minimal delay, to the other.  Each of the web interfaces allows me to subscribe to remote calendars, but the subscriptions are unfortunately read-only, so that doesn't help.

I've looked at a few approaches already, but haven't found anything satisfactory.  The most promising seemed to be [syncevolution](https://syncevolution.org/), which could be used to synchronize the remote calendars with local databases, but it wasn't clear whether I could (1) sync them both to a **single** local database or (2) sync them to separate local databases but keep these local databases in sync somehow.  One of these would be required to do what I want.

Is there a way to achieve my aim here?

Comment: Views, but no takers yet, so I'm wondering if I've asked in the wrong place or if it wasn't clear what I was looking for.  I provided some research I did that didn't resolve my question and was hoping someone might point me someplace I hadn't looked.  (I'm relatively new at SO, so any suggestions on procedure would be welcome also.)

Comment: Great opportunity to plug my own software here: vdirsyncer can do that. https://github.com/untitaker/vdirsyncer

Comment: One of the two calendars I want to sync is a Google calendar, and vdirsyncer doesn't seem to be able to do that, at least according to one of its open github tickets.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Markus' answer wasn't converted to an answer, but I can confirm that vdirsyncer will do this.

If it is still true that gContacts doesn't work, that is because Google's implementation is completely borked - and that wasn't in the question in the first place anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This question has now been [answered](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mobile.syncevolution/4623/focus=4624) on the SyncEvolution mailing list.  Short summary:  yes, SyncEvolution can be configured to do this kind of job, but it relies on newer features that have not been well documented.  The linked thread contains specific configuration instructions.  In a few days, I'll edit this answer to include my experiences setting it up.

Comment: It would be very valuable to have very specific instructions for this. The syncevolution configuration is confusing, at best. The thread you linked does not seem to cover the direct sync approach. Looking forward to read your experiences.

Comment: An update: still no solution with syncevolution -- "confusing, at best" turns out to be an understatement. I wish I had more to report.